# metadata applications

Tags: metadata, applications, use, use-of, labels

I was under the impression that meta data included time code but apparently it is the track information on mp3's as well?

How do I add metadata to things like my recordings and sound library/ies I see there is a related question here and I would like to know how to do it and why it is useful?

Answer (score 1):

uhmm why did I not know about this resource earlier ?? BWF MetaEdit for managing and batch editing metadata !FREE!, cross-platform .. have I died and gone to heaven ??!!

http://www.digitizationguidelines.gov/guidelines/digitize-embedding.html

http://bwfmetaedit.sourceforge.net/

http://sourceforge.net/projects/bwfmetaedit/files/binary/bwfmetaedit-gui/1.2.0/

Comment: I've been checking the BWF MetaEdit and I see a lot of possibilities for tagging my sound library files. However, my question is: which program will allow me to search and browse the tagged files? For example, if I use the field file description, and add tags like interior, walla, etc., how can I find the right file I need while working on ProTools?

Comment: Have a look at the Related tool bar on the right of this page. There are already half a dozen questions where this is discussed.

Comment: I'll elaborate my post (I've been reading around, but I cannot find exactly what I'm looking for): I have tagged some test files using the field Description on the BWF MetaEdit app. Now I'm trying to make a search on this metadata. So far, I have tested the searching capabilities of Audio Finder, Ableton Live, iTunes and Pro Tools. Only Pro Tools seems to display my tags (they appear in the File Comment field) but it searches only in the Name field. This makes my tags not useful. Has anybody had a positive experience with this workflow? Thanks!

Comment: Update: I just found that this search feature was not available in Pro Tools LE versions. But in Pro Tools 10 you can search in any data column of the DigiBase browsers!

Answer (score 0):

http://kid3.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

If you are only using MP3s, there are may ways to alter/add metadata.  For MP3s the metadata is called ID3 tags:

http://www.id3.org/

There are many different ways of altering the metadata in an MP3, iTunes is probably the easiest (if you use a mac and itunes as your library), there is also a program called Library Monkey which is much more versatile:

http://www.monkey-tools.com/products/library-monkey/

The other format that works well with metadata is Broadcast WAV (BWAV). Programs such as Soundminer work well with bwav files.  Soundminer's metadata format is slightly different than ID3 but most of the same information is there and you can change and alter as needed.  Also, many SFX libraries come already with Soundminer metadata added so all you need to do is "add to library" and you are rolling. Also, if you export WAV files from Pro Tools, the Timecode location is burned into the file as well (often required when exporting final mixes and stems for delivery)

If you are creating sound files to have in your own library, and you have the space available, I wouldn't compress down to MP3 just to use metadata, you can never get back to your full-rez audio after that.

Answer (score 0):

http://sbooth.org/Max/

As Ryan mentioned, I don't see why you would use compressed audio for your recordings, however metadata or tags may make your life easier when looking for a specific file in your personal (if messy like mine) library.

Other options if you use .wav

http://www.sounddevices.com/products/waveagent/

Or if you use logic from Apple you should have something called "apple loop utility" under software/utilities which let you tag files too.